# Can we add php comments before declaring namespace

Tags: php, oop, syntax, namespaces, comments

I would like to add PHP comments before declaring namespace.

```
<?php
    /*
     *  This is custom namespace
     *  Purpose : to give an example of namespace
    **/

    namespace myNameSpace{
        class myNewClass{
            /*
                code
            */
        }
    }
?>
```

This does not throw any errors but I am not sure if this will work in higher PHP versions. I am using 5.3.3.

For me using below code is just boring

```
<?php   
    namespace myNameSpace{
        /*
         *  This is custom namespace
         *  Purpose : to give an example of namespace
        **/

        class myNewClass{
            /*
                code
            */
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it's a comment, you can write them anywhere you like. future versions will be ignore them until /* .... */ format changes (I don't think that will be happen in near future)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's parser ignores comments. You can safely place them before or after namespace declarations without concern.

Comment: @UdayHirawale accept it if it helped. Also, you SHOULD google about first!

Comment: @sitilge Actually I did. I got confused with html output and comments.